# A better alternative for the word 'urine'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am writing a religious article that's related to urine. Since it will be on a religious website, I don't want this word 'URINE' to be in its heading. Please suggest a good word.

Comment: Use a different title?

Comment: If the word "urine" shouldn't appear in the title, why is it allowable as the subject of the article? Anyway, more context might allow formulating an answer which doesn't use the word but can give the idea. At the moment, all we have is "the article is about urine".

Comment: Article not yet written. Still framing the title.

Comment: Is this question [taking the piss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taking_the_piss)? (For the sarcasm impaired, there are *many* colloquialisms for urine *8')

Comment: How about "liquid excretory product"?

Comment: Wasn't this the fine film where the Professor type suggested that we should not [take the piss out of urine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion:_Tank_Police).

Comment: What would your title be -with- 'urine'? That'll give us a better idea of how to reword things.

Comment: Urine is what the medical community uses...are your readers so conflicted they cannot see that word without being offended?

Comment: This should have been closed a long time ago...

Comment: @Cascabel: Agreed. But there's no time like the present.

Comment: @Robusto "That's just passing water under the bridge"

Comment: @Mitch: */facepalm*

Comment: Guys...are we getting into a pissing contest here...?

Comment: @Cascabel: You mean a micturation competition?

Comment: @Cascabel Robusto, Ooh...how about "Don't micturate down my dorsal region and tell me it's precipitating dihydrogen oxide."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By far, the most common euphemisms for *urine* (n.) are ***pee*** and ***number one***. Beyond those, there are more: *excretion, liquid body waste, P, piddle, tinkle, waste, water, wee, wee-wee*.

In a religious context, the choices are different. Not knowing which religion you mean, I compared fifteen translations of 2 Kings 18:27 (a sacred text from my cultural tradition) and found the following:

- ***urine*** (8 translations)
- ***water*** (4 translations)
- excretion (1 translation)
- piss (1 translation: not a euphemism any more, but this was the term common at the time of King James)
- waste (1 translation)

On a side note, there are also plenty of euphemisms for *urinate*, and those get interesting. For example, apparently the English *spend a penny*. One of my good friends always says he has to *see a man about a horse*.

Comment: At first I was a bit confused by "not a euphemism anymore". (I've heard "take a piss" often enough, and I'm not old enough to remember King James. But then I read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taking_the_piss), and wondered if that's what you were referring to, maybe?) P.S. I chuckled rather heartily at number one – a clever headline writer might be able to embed a rather witty pun using that terminology.

Comment: "number one" is most common?  Any sources for that (apart from Google which is clearly useless here)?  Never heard of it.  Oh, I see it's used in schools a lot.  US schools, I surmise.  So... wouldn't know it.  Do adults use it?

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard: I'm not sure about "most common," but the expression is indeed widely understood, and often used when one wants to (how to say this delicately?) distinguish between a #1 and a #2. This lingo is frequently employed between parents and small children, but it might get used between adults on occasion, too. For example, such a dialog might run something like this: "I have to use the rest room." "How long will you be?" "Not long, I'm just going #1..."

Comment: Good for you including the word *wee* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/wee_2

Answer (score 11):

I suppose you could use "micturition", but really, "urine" is the correct scientific term, and no-one will know what you are talking about if you do change it.

Comment: with an i instead a?!

Comment: Thanks.  Corrected now.  Got it confused with some Vogon poetry.

Comment: As noted in another answer, *micturition* means *urination*, not *urine*, so be careful not to simply substitute it for *urine* in the article.

Comment: What MetaEd said. (And I also said in an answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use a more general term such as ["bodily fluid" or "biofluid"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_fluid) in your title, and then make it clear what your specific subject is (urine) in the introduction.

Comment: This answer reads partly like discussion. Suggest moving that part to a comment on Christi's answer.

Comment: @MetaEd, Good point, but I wasn't quite sure how to handle it since the answer was already accepted. I will add it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

For a chemical slant, you could try aqueous urea.

Answer (score -1):

Merriam-Webster's definiton of **effluent** includes:

> liquid that is released as waste

I consider the term technical, rather than clinical or medical.

Answer (score -2):

The Bible uses the word, "piss." Why not just use piss? That's the correct and proper English word for that liquid.

Comment: Which translation is that?

Comment: This possibility has already been noted in MetaEd's answer.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Urban Dictionary, probably.